# How to join by column name

Tags: sql, join, sybase

I have a table T1 such that

```
gsdv   |nsdv  |esdv
-------------------
228.90 |216.41|0.00
```

and a table T2 such that

```
ds                 |nm
--------------------------
'Non-Revenue Sales'|'ESDV'
'Gross Sales'      |'GSDV'
'Net Sales'        |'NSDV'
```

How do I get the following table?

```
ds                 |nm    |val
---------------------------------
'Non-Revenue Sales'|'ESDV'|0.00
'Gross Sales'      |'GSDV'|228.90
'Net Sales'        |'NSDV'|216.41
```

I know that I can do this with the following

```
SELECT ds,nm,esdv val FROM T1,T2 WHERE nm = 'esdv'
UNION
SELECT ds,nm,gsdv val FROM T1,T2 WHERE nm = 'gsdv'
UNION
SELECT ds,nm,nsdv val FROM T1,T2 WHERE nm = 'nsdv'
```

but I am looking for a more generic/nicer solution. I am using Sybase, but if you can think of a way to do this with other DBMS, please let me know. 
Thanks.

Comment: Remember that `UNION` is slower than `UNION ALL` because it tries to remove duplicates. If you have no duplicates, use `UNION ALL`

Answer (score 1):

You could try it with a CASE. Which would look something like

```
SELECT ds,nm,(CASE WHEN nm = 'esdv' THEN esdv WHEN nm = 'gsdv' THEN gsdv WHEN nm = 'nsdv' THEN nsdv END) val FROM T1,T2
```